# How to measure Cache or TLB misses on ARM Cortex-A15

Tags: caching, statistics, arm, tlb

Off late i am profilling my application on ARM Cortex-A15 and observed more cache misses  in  one function which take three arguments from global buffers. The function is sinple IIR filter which accesses states at start and updates states  at the end. If i use state as such it goes for toss and gives huge cache misses. If i copy state values in to local buffer to that function and use local copy of the state throughout the function gives less cache misses. The size of the state is hardly 10 values of int type. Could you please through some insight whats happening in cache front? How to avoid this kind of senario?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard from the small amount of info you give to know for sure, but I would strongly suspect cache pollution as your explanation. If you roll through a bunch of buffers, you're stuff them into cache and maybe dirtying them. As you go along, the cache effectively is filled by the old buffer data that's dutifully (and unfortunately, in your case) being maintained by the CPU's cache long after you're done with it.

If you copy the state values into your local buffer you modify only the one copy of the data instead of modifying it in place spread throughout the memory across all those global buffer addresses. You're still filling up cache with the data from the buffers you blow through, but these are not "dirty" cache lines - i.e., not modified. You're only dirtying a small number (a few) of cache lines for the modified state since your local buffer is always overwriting the same addresses over and over. Dirty cache lines have to be written back to memory when they need to be reused. But clean, readonly cache lines (like for your global buffers) can simply be overwritten when their cache lines need to be reused. This is a substantial savings.

You're not clear whether your modified state is actually stored in the buffers later or not. If you really want help on this, it would help to show the sequence and some code or pseudocode to show what's going on.